# Using Cucumber, how do I specify a condition that must hold after every step?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I am new to Cucumber and BDD. I was wondering if there is a good way to specify a condition that must be checked after every step. For example, suppose I want to make sure a particular variable x is equal to 5 after every step.  I do not want to write the scenario like this:

```
When something happens
Then x should be 5

When something else happens
Then x should be 5

And so on...
```

Is there a less repetitive way of accomplishing this?  I am aware of Background and hooks, but these seem to be for setting up the environment rather than verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AfterStep-hook (see https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks). This code will run after *every* step.

Alternatively you can decorate the scenarios with tags an just have the hook run for after steps in the tagged scenarios